# How to return null on select in a ListView using Xamarin Prism EventToCommand behavior

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using `Prism` with `Xamarin.Forms` and i'm trying to get the `ItemTapped` event command to return null so the `ListView` Item doesn't stay selected. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Here is my behavior code:

`<ListView.Behaviors>
  <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" EventArgsParameterPath="Item" />
</ListView.Behaviors>`

Comment: Are you looking to make the ViewCell selection toggleabe?  Or do you just want the ListView to disallow selection of its ViewCells?

Comment: I just don't want the list item to stay selected since i'm using it in a menu across the app.

Comment: So you want to disable the highlight?

Comment: @McHat Yeah that's what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I used this code to make my ListView function like what you might call a scrollable navbar:

```
private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item != null && ItemClickCommand != null && ItemClickCommand.CanExecute(e))
  {
    ItemClickCommand.Execute(e.Item);
    SelectedItem = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's close, but `Prism` has the `EventToCommandBehavior` built in, so I was trying to use theirs if possible.